# Android Studio, TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm building an app, trying to set the result of a series of clicks on buttons as the text of a TextView in a layout. My problem is app crashes when i push the last button in the last activity, where this result must be shown. I post the code here, wishing you can help me. Thanks.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Riepilogo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Riepilogo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT1"
        android:text="TAV. 1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT2"
        android:text="TAV. 2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT3"
        android:text="TAV. 3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT4"
        android:text="TAV. 4"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT5"
        android:text="TAV. 5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button19"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT6"
        android:text="TAV. 6"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button20"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT7"
        android:text="TAV. 7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT8"
        android:text="TAV. 8"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT9"
        android:text="TAV. 9"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button24"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT10"
        android:text="TAV. 10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button26"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT11"
        android:text="TAV. 11"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button27"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-11dp"
        android:onClick="OnButtonClickT12"
        android:text="TAV. 12"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ttvv"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="455dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"

        android:autoText="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:numeric="decimal"
        android:text="@string/rpg" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
public class Riepilogo extends Tavolo {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_riepilogo);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    }


    String t=String.valueOf(R.string.rpg); //rpg is the id of text in TextView


    public void OnButtonClickT1(View v){
        if(riep1.isEmpty() || tav1==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 1: "+riep1+" TOTALE: "+tav1+" EURO");

        }

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT2(View v){
        if(riep2.isEmpty() || tav2==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 2: "+riep2+" TOTALE: "+tav2+" EURO");}
    }
    public void OnButtonClickT3(View v){
        if(riep3.isEmpty() || tav3==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 3: "+riep3+" TOTALE: "+tav3+" EURO");}

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT4(View v){
        if(riep4.isEmpty() || tav4==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 4: "+riep4+" TOTALE: "+tav4+" EURO");}
    }
    public void OnButtonClickT5(View v){
        if(riep5.isEmpty() || tav5==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 5: "+riep5+" TOTALE: "+tav5+" EURO");}

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT6(View v){
        if(riep6.isEmpty() || tav6==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 6: "+riep6+" TOTALE: "+tav6+" EURO");}
    }
    public void OnButtonClickT7(View v){
        if(riep7.isEmpty() || tav7==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 7: "+riep7+" TOTALE: "+tav7+" EURO");}

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT8(View v){
        if(riep8.isEmpty() || tav8==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 8: "+riep8+" TOTALE: "+tav8+" EURO");}
    }
    public void OnButtonClickT9(View v){
        if(riep9.isEmpty() || tav9==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 9: "+riep9+" TOTALE: "+tav9+" EURO");}

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT10(View v){
        if(riep10.isEmpty() || tav10==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 10: "+riep10+" TOTALE: "+tav10+" EURO");}
    }
    public void OnButtonClickT11(View v){
        if(riep11.isEmpty() || tav11==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 11: "+riep11+" TOTALE: "+tav11+" EURO");}

    }
    public void OnButtonClickT12(View v){
        if(riep12.isEmpty() || tav12==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Niente da mostrare qui" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
        t=("TAVOLO 12: "+riep12+" TOTALE: "+tav12+" EURO");}
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please also post stack trace of the error when your app crashes? It can be seen in logcat

Comment: you should use `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); ` before your `setContentView()`

Comment: thanks for interest but this is not the problem... all activities "the orientation code" after and work...